# Upgrading python flask runtime to 37 in app.yml file breaks app

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

Got this message from google https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/migrate-to-python3 and am trying to change my runtime to python 3 e.g:

```
    application: myapp
    version: 5
    runtime: python37

   api_version: 1
   threadsafe: true
   default_expiration: 10m

   libraries:
   - name: ssl
   version: "latest"

   handlers:
   - url: .*
   script: run.application
   - url: /static
   static_dir: static
   expiration: 10m
```

Also note I run my app using google cloud SDk version  274.0.0 so i run something like:
dev_appserver app.yml 
Here is my error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chuks/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 96, in <module>
    _run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "/home/chuks/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py", line 90, in _run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "/home/chuks/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 608, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/chuks/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 596, in main
    dev_server.start(options)
  File "/home/chuks/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/devappserver2.py", line 273, in start
    env_variables=parsed_env_variables)
  File "/home/chuks/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 966, in __init__
    env_variables)
  File "/home/chuks/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 140, in __init__
    self._config_path)
  File "/home/chuks/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/application_configuration.py", line 524, in _parse_configuration
    config, files = appinfo_includes.ParseAndReturnIncludePaths(f)
  File "/home/chuks/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/appinfo_includes.py", line 82, in ParseAndReturnIncludePaths
    appyaml = appinfo.LoadSingleAppInfo(appinfo_file)
  File "/home/chuks/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/appinfo.py", line 2672, in LoadSingleAppInfo
    listener.Parse(app_info)
  File "/home/chuks/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/yaml_listener.py", line 242, in Parse
    stream, loader_class, version=version, **loader_args))
  File "/home/chuks/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/yaml_listener.py", line 180, in _HandleEvents
    raise yaml_errors.EventError(e, event_object)
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: libraries entries are only supported by the "python27" runtime
  in "app.yaml", line 35, column 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading your configuration file, I understand that your application is under the Standard App Engine Environment. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Quoting the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#migrating_between_python_2_and_python_3_on_the_app_engine_standard_environment),

> “The Python 3 runtime on the App Engine standard environment is
>   significantly different from the Python 2 runtime.”

If you decide to migrate your application from Python 2 to Python 3 on the App Engine standard environment, you should be aware of the following differences:

- [Compatibility issues between Python 2 and Python 3](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#compatibility_issues_between_python_2_and_python_3)
- [Fewer restrictions on the runtime environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#fewer_restrictions_on_the_runtime)
- [No App Engine APIs, changes to app.yaml, and local development](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#changes_to_the_app_engine_standard_environment)

By looking through the information regarding the last bullet (changes to app.yaml), I realize that the behavior of some fields in the app.yaml configuration file has been modified. The “**libraries**” field has been **deprecated** and arbitrary third party dependencies can be installed using a "*requirements.txt*" metadata file.

---

Could you try removing the “libraries” section from your app.yaml file and deploy again?

---

**EDIT:**

---

By default App Engine looks for an app variable in a file called main.py. According to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup) the runtime starts your application by using the contents of the optional entrypoint field in your app.yaml file. You can try configuring that entrypoint by using your own app with something like:

```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT run.application:main
```

Additionally the main.py has to be in root of your application, where app.yaml is.

In general I would recommend you to upgrade your local system to Python 3 too, as [Python 2.7  will not be maintained past 2020](https://pythonclock.org/). Subsequently I suggest that you read thoroughly through the documentation about [local development](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#local_development) and using the [local development server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/testing-and-deploying-your-app#local-dev-server).

---

**EDIT 2**:

Assert condition is a debugging condition and throws an Exception error if the logical condition (the one you see in the log message) is false.

This happens because according to the documentation ([link1](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#local_developmen), [link2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/testing-and-deploying-your-app#local-dev-server)) I posted on my previous edit,

> running dev_appserver requires the presence of Python 2.7.12+ on your
>   local machine and if your OS is Windows the updated dev_appserver does
>   not support development of Python 3 apps.

According to [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/testing-and-deploying-your-app#running_locally) (some examples are being described as well here):

> To test your application's functionality in your local environment it is recommended
>   that you use standard Python tools, such as virtualenv to create
>   isolated environments and pytest to run unit tests and integration
>   tests rather than depending on dev_appserver, the local development
>   server provided with the Google Cloud SDK.

Please read through the documentation carefully, in order to comprehend and assimilate the differences between the Python 2 and Python 3 environments regarding App Engine.

Comment: Ok thanks, @Artemis I see a different behavior now I took out the libraries section in the app.yml file and ran it seems to install some application called gunicorn and here is what I get  also not my system is on python 2.7 I only change the runtime 
python version:ImportError: No module named 'main'
[2019-12-19 12:54:49 +0100] [25554] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 25554)
[2019-12-19 12:54:49 +0100] [25544] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2019-12-19 12:54:49 +0100] [25544] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

Comment: I have edited my answer with further information that could be helpful regarding your next error. You may check for the **EDIT** section at the end of the post.

Comment: I upgrded my local system to python 3 and I get this error
/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py  line 95, in <module>
    assert sys.version_info[0] == 2
AssertionError

Comment: Good morning. I further edited my answer, providing some more information apropos of the AssertionError exception. Please check **EDIT 2** section.

Comment: thanks @Artemis your guides were helpful am now able to run the app locally

Comment: I'm glad it works now. If my answer covered your question, please kindly accept it, in order to follow the Stackoverflow rules and give the appropriate visibility to your post. Thank you in advance.